# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was out of bounds

Tags: c#

I have a program in C# that works fine when I run it in Visual Studio.

But when I run the  file I get an error in main.

The error is:

*Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was out of bounds of the array*

My main:
The error Is at *int tala = convert.toInt32...*

```
namespace MultiplicationTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int tala = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
            MultiplicationTable test = new MultiplicationTable(tala);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: args had not values so you didn't pass any arguments to it

Comment: You should specify an argument for the program in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem :** When you run it from Visual Studio you are providing the arguments but when you run the program directly by double clicking on it you can not provide the arguments as it willbe invoked directly.

**Solution :** you need to provide command line arguments properly, follow the below steps to run your program from command line

**Step 1:** goto Command Prompt

**Step 2:** goto your program exe file path

**Step 3:** now execute the program by providing commandline arguments as below:

```
c:\myprogrampath\program.exe 12
```

Try This code to avoid Exceptions:

```
if(args.Length>0)
{
    int tala = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
    MultiplicationTable test = new MultiplicationTable(tala);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Command Line Arguments - Quiting");
}
```

Comment: How come it runs fine in VS? Does VS supply some standard arguments in debug mode?

Comment: I see. So the reason for it worekd when  run in VS was that I hada a number in Command line Arguemnts?

Comment: I added a number in Command Line Arguments earlier, so that must be the reason

Comment: @germi: he might have provided the arguments in VS by using properties option, but when OP double clicks on exe file there is no chance of giving arguments so it definatly throws exception

Comment: I see - from the question I didn't think he'd have supplied arguments in VS but not when executing the app.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,

as the poster before said, either you have to pass arguments to your program or you have to check, if args is not null with an if-statement and "catch" this error.

```
if(args) {
//here your code
}
```

Alternatively, you could try an try - catch statement:

```
try {
   //here you read the arguments and pass to a variable
}
catch(System.IndexOutOfRangeException) {
     //other codepart
}
```